# How to insert a view created as a block into another view

Tags: drupal-7

I have two views :

First view is created as a page (
    It has 8 rows).
Second view is created as a block

I need to insert the second view into first view as 7th row.

Can anyone please tell me .

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a view at the top/bottom of a view you can create a view type: Attachment, then you can add your attachment into another view.

The second solution is to create a Panel (https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and add your 2 blocks to your panel.

Cheers